# Performing a task based on multiple text box values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning VBA. Two things:

1. Is there anything that is more efficient than that long elseif
   command ( I am trying to find the lowest textbox value)
2. Shapes appear in my Excel sheet based on the lowest text box value. This
   works but only when I change the NBInv textbox which makes sense.
   However, that is not what I want my program to do. I want it to
   constantly monitor the values of each text box and find the lowest
   one.

**Sample Code:**

```
Private Sub NBInv_Change()

    If NBInv.Text = "0" Or NBInv.Text = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("NFlow").Visible = False

    ElseIf NBInv.Value < NEBInv.Text And NBInv.Text < NEBInv.Text _
    And NBInv.Text < EBInv.Text And NBInv.Text < SEBInv.Text _
    And NBInv.Text < SBInv.Text And NBInv.Text < SWBInv.Text _
    And NBInv.Text < WBInv.Text And NBInv.Text < NWBInv.Text Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("NFlow").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("FlowNFalse").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have a different shape corresponding to each textbox?

Comment: You can use `Select Case` statement in place of `IF ElseIf` statement. But in your example, I think more appropriate would be to use a loop (e.g. `For Loop`)

Comment: Would the textboxes only ever hold numbers?

Comment: Side note: `TextBox.Text` value is always a string, even if it _looks_ like a number.  Whatever solution you settle on, cast the `.Text`'s to numbers with `CLng` or `CDbl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify setting the Visible properties in your code. Val(NBInv.Value) will return 0 for all non-numeric values and the number 0. CBool() converts 0 to False and all others to True.

```
Private Sub Solution()
    Dim HasValue As Boolean

    HasValue = CBool(Val(NBInv.Value))
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("NFlow").Visible = HasValue
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("FlowNFalse").Visible = Not HasValue
End Sub
```

The following function will return the one with the lowest value among all the controls listed.

> Private Function Smallest()
>
> ```
> Dim Fun As Variant
> Dim Tmp As Variant
> Dim Inv() As String
> Dim i As Integer
>
> Inv = Split("NBInv NEBInv EBInv SEBInv SBInv SWBInv WBInv NWBInv")
> Fun = 10 ^ 6
> For i = 0 To UBound(Inv)
>     Tmp = Val(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(Inv(i)).Object.Value)
>     If Tmp < Fun Then Fun = Tmp
> Next i
> Smallest = Fun
> ```
>
> End Function

The variable Fun must be set to a value which is larger than any you expect to encounter in the textboxes. I chose 10^6.

Comment: So i am trying the code you mentioned Variatus. It makes sense to me however i'm running in to a weird result. If i keep  " If Tmp < Fun Then Fun = Tmp" The variable Fun does not change for some reason and remains at 1000 causing the smallest to equal 1000. However if i change it to > to give me the biggest value it works...

Comment: The code works. Therefore Tmp isn't smaller than 1000. Examine Tmp.

Comment: For that matter, look at Fun, too. It might not be numeric. Try Tmp = Val(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(Inv(i)).Object.Value).

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Min(ParamArray values() As Variant)
       Dim minValue, Value As Variant
       minVal = values(0)
       For Each Value In values
          If  minVal > Value Then minVal = Value
       Next
       Min = minVal
End Function
```

You can use this code to find a minimum value.

```
Private Sub NBInv_Change()

     If NBInv.Text = "0" Or NBInv.Text = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("NFlow").Visible = False

     ElseIf Val(NBInv.Value) = Min(Val(txt1.value),Val(txt2.value),Val(txt3.value),Val(txt4.value)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("NFlow").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("FlowNFalse").Visible = False
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go by putting the following code in the relevant worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Const tbNames As String = "NBInv NEBInv EBInv SEBInv SBInv SWBInv WBInv NWBInv" '<--| list all your relevant XBInv textboxes names
Const shpXFlowNames As String = "NFlow NEFlow EFlow SEFlow SFlow SWFlow WFlow NWFlow"  '<--| list all "XFlow" shapes names corresponding to each XBInv textboxe
Const shpFlowXFalseNames As String = "FlowNFalse FlowNEFalse FlowEFalse FlowSEFalse FlowSFalse FlowSWFalse FlowWFalse FlowNWFalse" '<--| list all "FlowXFalse" shapes names corresponding to each XBInv textboxe
Dim tbs As Variant, shpXFlows As Variant, shpFlowXFalses As Variant

Sub CheckTB()
    Dim minVal As Long
    Dim iShp As Long
    Dim iTbMin As Long

    tbs = Split(tbNames) '<--| fill the array with textboxes names
    shpXFlows = Split(shpXFlowNames) '<--| fill the array with "XFlow" shapes names
    shpFlowXFalses = Split(shpFlowXFalseNames) '<--| fill the array with "FlowXFalse" shapes names

    minVal = GetMinVal(iTbMin)
    For iShp = 0 To UBound(shpXFlows) '<--| loop through shapes to hide all "XFlow"s and unhide all "FlowXFalse"s
        Shapes(shpXFlows(iShp)).Visible = False
        Shapes(shpFlowXFalses(iShp)).Visible = True
    Next
    Shapes(shpXFlows(iTbMin)).Visible = True '<--| unhide "XFlow" shape with minimum value
    Shapes(shpFlowXFalses(iTbMin)).Visible = False '<--| hide "FlowXFalse" shape with minimum value
End Sub

Function GetMinVal(iTbMin As Long) As Long
    Dim iTb As Long

    iTbMin = 0 '<--|initialize textbox index with minimum value to the first one
    GetMinVal = OLEObjects(tbs(iTbMin)).Object.Value '<--|initialize textbox with minimum value to the first one
    For iTb = 0 To UBound(tbs)
        If CLng(OLEObjects(tbs(iTb)).Object.Value) < GetMinVal Then
            GetMinVal = CLng(OLEObjects(tbs(iTb)).Object.Value)
            iTbMin = iTb
        End If
    Next
End Function


Private Sub EBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub NEBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub NBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub NWBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub SBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub SEBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub SWBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub

Private Sub WBInv_Change()
    CheckTB
End Sub
```